# Accessing the LAN cable at the back of a server with no back or side access

Tags: networking, lan, switch, rack

I’m new to networking and how things are usually done, and I’m having a specific issue I need to figure out.

The issue I’m having is, that I need to figure out what switch a specific file server is connected to.
The server rack is set-up in a way, where I do not have access behind it or on the side of it.

My concerns are:
If I pull the server out from the rack, will the cables be disconnected.
Or that the server mounted on-top of the one I need access too, will block access to check the back side connections.

I would think, I need to turn the server off before trying to remove it?
and pull it out and check the markings on the network cable?

What would you do in a scenario like this?

Comment: I would first ask the system administrators how they access the server when a power supply or disk has to be replaced. Second, I would talk to the facilities manager (or whoever approved the placement) and insist that the rear of the rack be made accessible. Under no circumstances should you try to pull the server forward without knowing how much slack is in the cables.

Answer (score 1):

If the servers in the rack have been installed correctly, they will be on sliding rails. They all come with flexible cable management which makes sure the cabling does not pull out anything. Advise to speak with IT support beforehand.

Comment: I am the on-site IT support, but I'm not the one thats has done the config.
I'll try to ask the network team to clarify, or contact the person that did the set-up.
Thanks

Comment: do you have something less important or redundant in there? could try pulling that first and see

Answer (score 0):

Every switch maintains a table of what MAC addresses are behind each physical port. If the server is alive at all, the network admin should be able to search for its MAC address in every switch. If the network's documentation says that the port goes to another switch – repeat the search from the next switch, until you reach the server.

Comment: This makes sense, I did not think about this.
I don't really  see the reason for me physically having to check the connection, I would not think the cable has broken.
Rather sounds like a issue with the switch routing then physical.

Thanks

Comment: Most switches (and some server Ethernet NICs) also have a built-in TDR cable test function.

Comment: For me it seems the network team, does not know what port the server is even connected at.
If the port is NC, I would imagne the network card is the issue rather then a physical cable.

Comment: Well, they could find out either from the MAC table, or if the link is completely failed, by ruling out all ports that they _know_ are either a) working or b) physically not connected (i.e. no cable) and then testing the ones that remain...